# RAILS: Editing old migration files to solve ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have a few old migration files that contain a change method. When executing `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` they give an `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration`, I can change the migration to have and up and down method, which solves the error on my local machine, but is this a good idea or will it cause problems? For example when deploying to production?

What is the right way of solving this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: At least changing old migrations may cause problems when you're developing your project with your remote teammates.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb is: Changing old migrations is ok, when either:

1. It has never been run anywhere else (e.g. you are the only developer and it hasn't been deployed yet)
2. It has already been run in production

I personally like to have all migrations work from any point on my local machine so that when something goes wrong I can just execute:

```
rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate
```

The only problem that I see is, when your changing of the migration would significantly change the schema. Then you'd end up with a different schema in production and development. This might cause problems with debugging and bug fixing.